# Unity error: 'Animator' does not contain a definition for 'Setbool'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I am new to coding in c# and I don't know what the problem is with this code, I am trying to make a game where you can walk left and right and an animation plays and if you press down or up it takes out a parasol.

```
public int idleCheck = 5;

Animator A_anim;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    A_anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("LeftRight"))
    {
        idleCheck = 2;
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Vertical"))
    {
        idleCheck = 1;
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("LeftRight"))
    {
        idleCheck = 3;
    }

    if (idleCheck == 3)
    {
        A_anim.Setbool("ParaRun", true);
    }
    else if (idleCheck == 3)
    {
        A_anim.Setbool("ParaRun", false);
    }
    if (idleCheck == 2)
    {
        A_anim.Setbool("RunNor", true);
    }
    else if (idleCheck == 2)
    {
        A_anim.Setbool("RunNor", false);
    }
    if (idleCheck == 1)
    {
        A_anim.Setbool("parasole ability", true);
    }
    else if (idleCheck == 1)
    {
        A_anim.Setbool("parasole ability", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try with ```SetBool```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Setbool does not exist but SetBool does :). Just a typo, you can check their [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetBool.html) for more details.